# Implementing zero mean and unit variance in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, normalization

I am given a definition of a function and asked to implement it as follows:

```
# Problem 1 - Apply zero mean and zero variance scale to the image features
def normalize(data):
    pass
```

Then provided with a unit test using `numpy` that would assert the success of my implementation

**EDIT**

This **not** my unit test, but assigned by the instructor of the course.

```
np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(
    normalize(np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])),
    np.array([-0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.099, 0.0, 0.099, 0.199, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]),
    decimal=3)
```

My solution is

```
def normalize(data):
    return ((data - data.mean()) / data.max() - data.min())
```

But there must be a gap in my understanding because I'm getting

```
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 3 decimals

(mismatch 100.0%)
 x: array([-1.45, -1.35, -1.25, -1.15, -1.05, -0.95, -0.85, -0.75, -0.65, -0.55])
 y: array([-0.4  , -0.3  , -0.2  , -0.099,  0.   ,  0.099,  0.199,  0.3  ,
        0.4  ,  0.5  ])
```

With googling I'm also finding

```
(data - data.mean()) / data.std()
```

After more searching I attempted

```
(data - data.mean()) / data.var()
```

But neither solution asserts correctly.

So what's the correct implementation here?

Answer (score 9):

First you probably intended to do this:

```
(data - data.mean()) / (data.max() - data.min())
```

instead of this:

```
((data - data.mean()) / data.max() - data.min())
```

Then it's is just not the correct definition for normalising. Instead, as you found by searching around, the correct definition is:

```
(data - data.mean()) / data.std()
```

And finally your unit test is just wrong, so it fails when called with the correct definition.

Comment: As the question stats, that's no my unit test! It was assigned by the instructor!

Comment: Then change your instructor ;) `np.array([-0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.099, 0.0, 0.099, 0.199, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]).std() =  0.28710675714792921` I don't see how this is normalised...

Comment: Also: "zero variance" means all values should be equal, which I doubt is what your instructor wants. So maybe ask your instructor to check his questions ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is likely a typo in your question. Note that the unit test passes if you use the formula

```
(data - data.mean()) / data.var()
```

But only if you append a `0` to the beginning of the test input array, and append a -0.5 to the beginning of the output array. If it's not a typo, then that is a strange coincidence.

Comment: Even if this is the case, normalising by the variance doesn't make much sense since it's not dimensionally correct: if your data is lengths in meters, the result of this 'normalisation' would be in meters^-1. I think the instructor's question is just plain wrong.